# ArcGIS Pro add partial filename to output filename in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I have a `spatial join` tool in my `model` that joins one `feature class` to another.

I am interested in inserting the `first few strings` of the `join feature class name` to the `output feature class name`.

In the example below the join feature class name is `LBT06162022Concatenated_Geoc`. So I want to add `LBT06162022` to the output feature class name as `BCGISAddressZipCodeLBT06162022`. Now I can do this manually, but the thing is the join feature class name could be different with updated data. Thus, in that case `LBT06162022Concatenated_Geoc` could be something like `LBT06302022Concatenated_Geoc`. Hence, the output feature class name would be `BCGISAddressZipCodeLBT06302022`.

[image]

[image]

I know you could do something along the lines of adding `%Name%` or something but that add the whole file name not partial.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any constants from the name of `LBT06162022`? Always 11 characters, always ends in 2022, always 8 numbers after always starting with LBT..... anything like that?

Comment: @KHibma, I think the only constant is `LBT`, because the rest is date so the year `2022` could go to `2023` next year (I wouldn't worry about the year part too much since 2023 is ways off and I can always a new question for that). But, yes always `11` characters and the same sequence `LBT` then two characters for `month`, two for `day` and last four for `year`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use the Model tool **Parse Path** and **Calculate Value**.
See the screen shot - Parse Path first finds the **Name**, for example, `LBT06162022Concatenated_Geoc`. You can then use Calculate Value to do some string manipulation to get the value you need. In your case, you want the first 11 characters, so the code block is pretty simple:

**Expression**

`parse('%Name%')`

**Code Block**

```
def parse(fileName):
  return str(fileName)[0:11]
```

You can see that the whole solution makes use of Inline Variables: Getting the **Name** from Parse Path into Calculate Value and then **parsed** from the output of Calculate Value as a mash up field name of `foo_%parsed%` for the output of Copy Features.

Note the connections are pre-conditions between:

- Name and Calculate Value
- Parsed and Copy Features

[image]

Comment: So, should I connect it with the `spatial join` tool via `input` in the model?

Comment: Yes, instead of Copy Features, you'd use Spatial Join